# Trouble identifying if we have a conditional probability problem or not.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following problem :
We have 2/3 of getting heads when we throw a coin.
We have 1/3 of getting tails when we throw a coin.

What is the probability of getting exactly two heads after three throws knowing that the first throw was a head.

My probability knowledge is a little bit rusty. I know that this looks like a conditional probability problem. I know that the formula for conditional probability is $P(X|Y) = \dfrac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}$.

Now I need to adapt this formula to our current problem. Initially we had a probability of $\dfrac{2}{3}$ of getting a heads. Wait... It seems that it does not matter what was the result at the first throw because the probability of getting a heads is still 2/3 at each throws it seems. Now I'm confused. Could someone help me clear this confusion? What should I do?

Comment: Bayes rule is overkill.  You can simply analyse what is the probability of getting one head in the next 2 throws.

Comment: Also, your cited formula for conditional probability is incorrect.  It should have been $\Pr(X\mid Y) = \dfrac{\Pr(X\cap Y)}{\Pr(Y)}$.  As for going about this the long way, letting $X$ be the event we got two heads in three throws, and $Y$ the event the first flip was a head, this winds up being $\dfrac{(\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3})}{\frac{2}{3}}$, the top corresponding to the probabilities of heads on first, heads on second and tails on third, or getting heads on first tails on second and heads on third.

Comment: oups I fixed the error in the formula. Thank you.

Comment: There are only $8$ possibilities to consider.